# Why do Canon 7D RAW files come up colorless in Canon DPP?

Tags: software, raw, troubleshooting, canon-7d, canon-dpp

I have problem with DPP 3.12.40.0. When I import CR2 files (RAW Files) from my 7D to edit, DPP shows images very poorly (colorless). I searched on the net and can't find any explanation or solution. My camera preview screen shows them as normal with color. Why does DPP show my RAW files without color?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Can you post a sample screenshot of what you are seeing? Can you update to the current version and try again? The current version is 3.12.52 it appears.

Comment: Solved. The problem is update problem. After I updated the DPP it works fine. Thanks dpollitt

Comment: @AkramMiriyev You should post that as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your installation of Digital Photo Professional was corrupted in some way. When you downloaded the update it reinstalled the latest version of the program and then applied your preferred settings that were stored in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo dpollitt's comment for a screenshot.

Spontaneously I would suggest you check the "styles" that Canon offers.

There is no setting that would suggest a black and white display when I look at DPP.

You have checked that your fast display is switched off (just in case) and that the colourspace (can be important) is set correctly?

Comment: Solved. The problem is update problem. After I updated the DPP it works fine. Thanks dpollitt